# Toad resultset: Visually highlight groups of rows

Tags: oracle, format, toad

*In Toad for Oracle 12:*

I have a query that has a WOGROUP column that groups workorders:

```
select
    wogroup,
    wonum,
    parent,
    istask,
    taskid
from
    maximo.workorder
```

[image]

---

It would be helpful if I could visually group the rows via the WOGROUP column. That would help make the resultset easier to read when reviewing a query's output.

Ideas might be:

- Borders or horizontal lines
- Grouped row shading (alternating by group)
- Coloring the grey column on the left hand side (alternating by group)

---

Example (border):

[image]

---

Is it possible to visually highlight groups of rows in the resultset like that?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, not as you want, but - see if this helps:

- right-click data grid
- select "Appearance" and then "**Toggle Group Panel**"
- drag column's header "up"

That's it.

Return to the *original* layout by selecting "Reset columns" in the right-click menu.

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. I have my own screenshot, but *sharing services* were unavailable to me at a time :)